# How to deserialize ProblemDetails in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a C# client app that calls an ASP.NET Core REST service. If the REST service fails on the server it is configured to return a 'problem details' json response as per [rfc7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807), e.g.:

```
{
    "type": "ServiceFault",
    "title": "A service level error occurred executing the action FooController.Create
    "status": 500,
    "detail": "Code=ServiceFault; Reference=5a0912a2-df17-4f27-8e5a-0d4828022306; Message=An error occurred creating a record.",
    "instance": "urn:foo-corp:error:5a0912a2-df17-4f27-8e5a-0d4828022306"
}
```

In the client app I would like to deserialize this json message to an instance of [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails) as a convenient way of accessing the details. E.g.:

```
ProblemDetails details = await httpResp.Content.ReadAsAsync<ProblemDetails>();
```

However, the deserialization throws the following exception:

> System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException: No MediaTypeFormatter
> is available to read an object of type 'ProblemDetails' from content
> with media type 'application/problem+json'.

Answer (score 4):

`ReadAsAsync<T>` is unfamiliar with the `application/problem+json` media type, and does not have a formatter that can handle that type by default, hence the error

You can use the long approach and get the string first then use Json.Net

```
string json = await httpResp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
ProblemDetails details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProblemDetails>(json);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define a `ProblemDetailsMediaTypeFormatter` that will inherit from `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`.

```cs
    public class ProblemDetailsMediaTypeFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public ProblemDetailsMediaTypeFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/problem+json"));
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```cs
var problemDetails = await response.Content
    .ReadAsAsync<ProblemDetails>(new [] { new ProblemDetailsMediaTypeFormatter() }, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Great answer, but there is a compile time error with this. 
It should be (new [] { new ProblemDetailsMediaTypeFormatter() }